# How to fix SMTP-AuthentificationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmail, actionmailer

I built a small contact-form to deliver a message with Rails. I followed the Rails-Guides on ActionMailer closely (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) - especially Point `5.2 Action Mailer Configuration for GMail` because I want to use Gmail for this purpose.

I am in development environment.

Problem: No messages appear at the specific email adress.

When checking the `development.log` I find:

```
Sent mail to // the specific email-address appears
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 13:26:37 +0100
From: // my gmail account 
To: rt@netlogix.de
Message-ID: <512f4cfdc419c_1b2020e4ab495633@PC-MYNAME.mail>
Subject: The Subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Am I missing something, or is this because I am in development?
Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Heres the configuration in `development.rb`:

```
# Configuring GMAIL
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "localhost:3000",
    :user_name            => "myemailaddress@gmail.com",
    :password             => "myPW",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**Edit 2:**

I thought that maybe our firewall is the problem so I pushed the project to heroku: Delivering still fails, but here is the log:

```
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
Sent mail to (email-adress) (690ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 712ms
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again.)
```

Comment: Have you used it? .....http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing

Comment: To be honest - I´m a humble beginner, not even a developer, and skipped all testing, and test to old try and error way...

Comment: ok try this one, seems nice.. http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/sending-email-in-rails/

Comment: Hmm, looks like I´m getting Timout Errors now. `execution expired`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved it.

First, internally I think our firewall restricted access from my localhost to googles smtp-server.

In production (on heroku) it seemed that google closed the access to my account after the first email. I had to log into my account, and confirm via sms that this is my account, now everything works nicely!